# how to prevent downloading if a file already exists

Tags: file, kotlin, download-manager

I am downloading images form URL and saving them in pictures directory in folder name unsplash. Now if a user has already downloaded an image I want to show an alert dialog that picture has already been downloaded and if the user wants to download it again. Please help me through it how can I do that.

```
 downloadBtn.setOnClickListener {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        baseContext,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    )
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    startDownloading(list,position)
                } else {
                    requestDownloadPermission()
                }
            }
        private fun requestDownloadPermission() {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )
            ) {
                val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                dialog.setTitle("Permission Required")
                dialog.setMessage("Permission Required for downloading this picture." +
                        "Please go to settings for accessing permission")
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Go to setting") { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
                    val openURL = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                    openURL.data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                    startActivity(openURL)
        
                }
                dialog.setNegativeButton("cancel") { _: DialogInterface, _: Int -> }
                dialog.show()
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
                )
            }
        }
        private fun startDownloading(list: ArrayList<ImageModel>, position: Int) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val downloadList = list[position].urls.raw
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadList))
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
                    "/unsplash/${list[position].id}.jpg"
                )
                .setTitle("Unsplash Images").setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            val manager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            myId = manager.enqueue(request)
            var br = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                    var id = intent?.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
                    if (id == myId) {
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Downloaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                }
            }
            registerReceiver(br, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
        }
        override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
            grantResults: IntArray
        ) {
            if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    val list = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("FULLIMAGELIST") as ArrayList<ImageModel>
                    val position = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION", 0)
                    startDownloading(list,position)
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
            
        }
```

Comment: Please format the code correctly

Comment: @LancesLance formatting done

Comment: You need to find the Kotlin wrapper to the [access(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) system call

Comment: I didn't get it brother @BasileStarynkevitch